# Android - Custom Dialog Class - How to close

Tags: android, class, dialog

So I created a **custom dialog** class, but when I try to dismiss it it won't close.

Here is the part of the code to close the dialog

```
public static void CountDownDialog(final Activity activity){

    countDownDialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.dialog);
    ...    
    negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss_dialog();
        }
    });

    countDownDialog.show();
    ...  
}
```

And the method supposed to close the dialog

```
private static void dismiss_dialog() {

    countDownDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your example you are not actually creating any custom dialog class. You are creating a normal dialog and setting that dialog as a member in your class but yiu are using static functions. Yon can try to return the dialog instant instead of setting it in that class then you will have a reference of your dialog instance from your caller and at anytime call dismiss on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Dialog;

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container, false);
    Button dismiss = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    getDialog().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

How to call;

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.show(fm, "");
```